# Why does Firefox freeze and stop my computer?

Tags: firefox, performance

I searched in previous answers and I did not find an answer. Maybe he does not search in the right way.
The problem I have is that working with my PC, ACER 5620Z, is going well.
But when I start Firefox, it freezes, and makes the other applications I have running, also freeze.
I tried disconnecting the SWAP, but the problem continues and I do not know what else to do.
If you give me any idea why it can happen.
Maybe I should uninstall and reinstall?
The problems I have had since I did something to put Firefox in Spanish, but I can not find the exact documentation to give them more information.
The Firefox version is 61.0.1 Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu. canonical - 1.0
Maybe I should install Google Chrome better?

> EDIT: When I start Firefox and Visual Studio Code at the same time is when the pc freezes.

I'm taking my first steps in Ubuntu, and I still have to learn.
Thank you

Comment: It could be due to a Firefox extension you have installed. Do you have many extensions installed? Also, please start Firefox in "safe mode" - does the issue still occur? (you can start Firefox in safe mode using: `$ firefox --safe-mode`).

Comment: Thanks @ Andy Turfer for the support. Install Easy Translate and Google Elinv Translator.
I'll eliminate them to see if it works better. But I need something to translate the pages that do not come in Spanish ....

Comment: Does it freeze forever or just pause for a time? I have noticed since installing 18.04 that when I reboot and start FF, it seems to "pause" the desktop for a brief time, then recovers. Oddly, this doesn't happen if I close FF and reopen it later.  Also, top, htop, etc don't show any issues.

Comment: Thanks @Organic Marble, it freezes a lot of time, two three minutes, and working in Visual Studio, it becomes impossible. I have removed the SWAP memory, I will put back to see if it works better

Comment: How much RAM and extensions do you have?

Comment: 2G RAM, with two processing cores

Comment: Thanks @dsstorefile, I will study how to put memory, if possible, to a laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - 
close firefox, open shell and write:

`cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/YOUR_FIREFOX_PROFILE`

```
mv places.sqlite places.sqlite.bak && mv webappsstore.sqlite webappsstore.sqlite.bak && mv favicons.sqlite favicons.sqlite.bak
```

This will delete/backup all your profile's history and web storage including cookies and web icons.

Remove any unwanted or new addons that have been added just before the the problems occur.

Restart firefox

EDIT: if it's still freezes ,sluggish or hangs I recommend to removing your current firefox installation: `sudo apt remove firefox` (it keeps the profile intact)

update to the latest build directly from mozilla's official PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
sudo apt upgrade
```

Install latest firefox build: `sudo apt install firefox`
then run it `firefox` (without sudo)
When the Icon appears on menu-bar right click and select *Add to Favorites* then you can run it directly using the UI.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Firefox. Using a Dell e6420. I rebooted computer,  uninstall Firefox, opened another browser (windows browser), went to Firefox site and installed a fresh Firefox. Has worked for 3 weeks now.

Comment: How did you open a Windows browser on Ubuntu?